# Cancel pending mail in Mandrill

Tags: email, magento, mailchimp, mandrill

For my Magento webshop I use Ebizmarts with Mandril to send autoresponder mails to customers. By an incorrect setting in Magento I activated accidentally an abandoned cart email sent to a large number of customers. I have tried to cancel sending. (there are still 2000 mails pending/ready to send) Unfortunately I can not find the option to delete the pending mails.

Meanwhile I paused the account so that no more e-mails are sent. Is this possible to delete this mailing?

Answer (score 1):

If the emails are in the account's backlog, you can clear (delete) them all: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582587. If they're already on Mandrill's servers ready to be delivered (i.e. you see a status of "Sent" on the Activity page), there's nothing you can do/you can't 'cancel' them from sending.

Comment: And if you want to delete only specific emails (for example, if you have some legitimate emails in your backlog that you need to send), you can set up a Rule to reject (not send) emails based on sender, tag, subject line, etc., then when you un-pause your account, those unwanted emails won't send: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583117-What-is-the-rules-engine-

Comment: Terrorbox's answer seems to be accurate, but I wasn't able to get the idea he/she posted in the comment above ^ to work. Meaning, I created a rule and paused/unpaused and it didn't seem to trigger the rules. Thanks for the info though.